# R regex extract substring followed by end of line or specific character (lazy match)

Tags: r, regex

I have a vector `mystr` the elements of which contain the unit of measure for a given parameter - this is indicated by the letters, symbols etc. following `UOM=`. This may be placed at the end of a string or delimited by a semicolon `;`

```
c("\\\\Server-01?6cf038ea-d583-4860-9488-67ee59c767c2\\expnum.2PDT35103?6438;TimeMethod=AtOrBefore;UOM=inHg;pointtype=Float32;displaydigits=1", 
"\\\\Server02-01?6cf038ea-d583-4860-9488-67ee59c767c2\\testnum.2BTAVGBARPR.OUT?6449;TimeMethod=AtOrBefore;UOM=inHg", 
"\\\\Server02-01?6cf038ea-d583-4860-9488-67ee59c767c2\\testnum3.2PT39248S.XQ01?6453;TimeMethod=AtOrBefore;UOM=psia;pointtype=Float32;displaydigits=1")
```

In the above example, I'd like to extract `inHg`, `inHg` and `psia` respectively. So far I've tried using `regmatches` and `regexec` but haven't found anything that works for all three examples here:

```
regex_func <- function(string, ptrn){
  return(regmatches(x = string, m = regexec(pattern = ptrn, text = string))[[1]][2])
}

> sapply(mystr, function(z){ regex_func(string = z, ptrn = '.*UOM=(.*)[$;]?')}, USE.NAMES = F)
[1] "inHg;pointtype=Float32;displaydigits=1" "inHg"                                  
[3] "psia;pointtype=Float32;displaydigits=1"

> sapply(mystr, function(z){ regex_func(string = z, ptrn = '.*UOM=(.*)[$;]+?')}, USE.NAMES = F)
[1] "inHg" NA     "psia"

> sapply(mystr, function(z){ regex_func(string = z, ptrn = '.*UOM=(.*)[$;]')}, USE.NAMES = F)
[1] "inHg;pointtype=Float32" NA                       "psia;pointtype=Float32"

> sapply(mystr, function(z){ regex_func(string = z, ptrn = '.*UOM=(.*)[$;]{0,1}')}, USE.NAMES = F)
[1] "inHg;pointtype=Float32;displaydigits=1" "inHg"                                  
[3] "psia;pointtype=Float32;displaydigits=1"
```

I'm not tied to `regmatches` and am open to using other functions/packages as well e.g. `stringr`, `stringi`

**EDIT**

Added. sample data Frame with all info - not all `ConfigString` elements have `UOM`.

```
structure(list(Name = c("Ambient Pressure", "Ambient RH", "Ambient Temperature", 
"Average Exhaust Gas Temp", "Bellmouth Temperature", "Compressor Discharge Pressure", 
"Compressor Discharge Temperature", "Current Power Output", "Degradation in Heat Rate (Comp Effic)", 
"Degradation in Power Output (Comp Effic)", "DirtPenetratingToEngineSinceLastWash", 
"Fuel Gas Temperature", "Fuel Heating Value (by volume)", "Fuel Volumetric Flow", 
"GT Fired Hours", "HRSG HP Steam Outlet Mass Flow", "HRSG HP Steam Outlet Pressure", 
"HRSG HP Steam Outlet Temperature", "HRSG IP Steam Outlet Mass Flow", 
"HRSG IP Steam Outlet Pressure", "HRSG IP Steam Outlet Temperature", 
"HRSG LP Steam Outlet Mass Flow", "HRSG LP Steam Outlet Pressure", 
"HRSG LP Steam Outlet Temperature", "Inlet Guide Vane Position", 
"Inlet system pressure drop", "Steam Injection Flow", "Steam Injection Pressure", 
"Steam Injection Temp"), DefaultUnitsName = c("kilopascal", "percent", 
"degree Celsius", "degree Celsius", "degree Celsius", "kilopascal", 
"degree Celsius", "megawatt", "kilojoule per kilowatt-hour", 
"megawatt", "gram", "degree Celsius", "BTU per standard cubic foot", 
"standard cubic foot per second", "hour", "kilogram per second", 
"kilopascal", "degree Celsius", "kilogram per second", "kilopascal", 
"degree Celsius", "kilogram per second", "kilopascal", "degree Celsius", 
"degree", "kilopascal", "kilogram per second", "pound-force per square inch", 
"degree Celsius"), DefaultUnitsNameAbbreviation = c("kPa", "%", 
"°C", "°C", "°C", "kPa", "°C", "MW", "kJ/kWh", "MW", "g", "°C", 
"BTU/scf", "scfs", "h", "kg/s", "kPa", "°C", "kg/s", "kPa", "°C", 
"kg/s", "kPa", "°C", "°", "kPa", "kg/s", "psi", "°C"), ConfigString = c("\\\\#\\asset1.2BTAVGBARPR.OUT?6449;TimeMethod=AtOrBefore;UOM=inHg", 
"\\\\#\\asset1.2BTAVGHUM.OUT?6423;TimeMethod=AtOrBefore", "\\\\#\\asset1.2BTAVGAMBTEMP.OUT?6446;TimeMethod=AtOrBefore;UOM=°F", 
"\\\\#\\asset1.2TEAVTX.ZQ01?6456;TimeMethod=AtOrBefore;UOM=°F", 
"\\\\#\\asset1.BT0110.CTGgtAIte01a?6802;TimeMethod=AtOrBefore;UOM=°F;pointtype=Float32;displaydigits=1", 
"\\\\#\\asset1.2PT39248S.XQ01?6453;TimeMethod=AtOrBefore;UOM=psia;pointtype=Float32;displaydigits=1", 
"\\\\#\\asset1.2TE35401S.XQ02?6457;TimeMethod=AtOrBefore;UOM=°F;pointtype=Float32;displaydigits=1", 
"\\\\#\\asset1.2JT38601S.XQ01?6450;TimeMethod=AtOrBefore;pointtype=Float32;displaydigits=1", 
"\\\\#\\Degradation in Heat Rate (Comp Effic)?6275;TimeMethod=AtOrBefore", 
"\\\\#\\Degradation in Power Output (Comp Effic)?6274;TimeMethod=AtOrBefore", 
"\\\\#\\Dust?6273;TimeMethod=AtOrBefore", 
"\\\\#\\asset1.2TE36112.XQ01?6454;TimeMethod=AtOrBefore;UOM=°F;pointtype=Float32;displaydigits=1", 
"\\\\#\\asset1.2FC54SUM.XQ01?6448;TimeMethod=AtOrBefore;pointtype=Float32;displaydigits=1", 
"\\\\#\\asset1.BT0110.CTGgtFGvl01a?6801;TimeMethod=AtOrBefore;pointtype=Float32;displaydigits=1", 
"\\\\#\\asset1.2CTGFiredHours?6800;TimeMethod=AtOrBefore;pointtype=Float32;displaydigits=1", 
"\\\\#\\asset1.2FT5050S.XQ01?6455;TimeMethod=AtOrBefore;pointtype=Float32;displaydigits=1", 
"\\\\#\\asset1.2PT5000S.XQ01?6799;TimeMethod=AtOrBefore;UOM=psi;pointtype=Float32;displaydigits=1", 
"\\\\#\\asset1.2TE5020S.XQ01?6798;TimeMethod=AtOrBefore;UOM=°F;pointtype=Float32;displaydigits=1", 
"\\\\#\\asset1.2FT5150S.XQ01?6447;TimeMethod=AtOrBefore;pointtype=Float32;displaydigits=1", 
"\\\\#\\asset1.2PT5100S.XQ01?6797;UOM=psi;pointtype=Float32;displaydigits=1", 
"\\\\#\\asset1.2TE5120S.XQ01?6796;TimeMethod=AtOrBefore;UOM=°F;pointtype=Float32;displaydigits=1", 
"\\\\#\\asset1.2FT5250S.XQ01?6443;TimeMethod=AtOrBefore;pointtype=Float32;displaydigits=1", 
"\\\\#\\asset1.2PT5200S.XQ01?6795;TimeMethod=AtOrBefore;UOM=psi;pointtype=Float32;displaydigits=1", 
"\\\\#\\asset1.2TE5220S.XQ01?6794;TimeMethod=AtOrBefore;UOM=°F;pointtype=Float32;displaydigits=1", 
"\\\\#\\asset1.2ZT35203.XQ01?6432;TimeMethod=AtOrBefore;pointtype=Float32;displaydigits=1", 
"\\\\#\\asset1.2PDT35103?6438;TimeMethod=AtOrBefore;UOM=inHg;pointtype=Float32;displaydigits=1", 
"\\\\#\\asset1.2FT36602X.ZQ01?6792;TimeMethod=AtOrBefore;pointtype=Float32;displaydigits=1", 
"\\\\#\\asset1.2PT245.XQ01?6793;TimeMethod=AtOrBefore;pointtype=Float32;displaydigits=1", 
"\\\\#\\asset1.2TE240.XQ01?6791;TimeMethod=AtOrBefore;UOM=°F;pointtype=Float32;displaydigits=1"
)), row.names = c(NA, -29L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
))

# 15 items returned 
> regmatches(x = dat$ConfigString, regexpr(pattern = '[?;]UOM=\\K[^;]+', text = dat$ConfigString, perl = T))
 [1] "inHg" "°F"   "°F"   "°F"   "psia" "°F"   "°F"   "psi"  "°F"   "psi"  "°F"   "psi"  "°F"   "inHg" "°F"
```

Using the chosen solution with this data:

```
# operation on a vector
> dat[, uom := regmatches(ConfigString, regexpr(pattern = '[?;]UOM=\\K[^;]+', ConfigString, perl = T))]

# using := operator in data.table
> dat[, uom := regmatches(ConfigString, regexpr(pattern = '[?;]UOM=\\K[^;]+', ConfigString, perl = T))]
Error in `[.data.table`(dat, , `:=`(uom, regmatches(ConfigString, regexpr(pattern = "[?;]UOM=\\K[^;]+",  : 
  Supplied 15 items to be assigned to 29 items of column 'uom'. If you wish to 'recycle' the RHS please use rep() to make this intent clear to readers of your code.
```

Using `stringr`

```
> stringr::str_replace(dat$ConfigString, ".*[?;]UOM=([^;]+).*", "\\1")
 [1] "inHg"                                                                                          
 [2] "\\\\#\\asset1.2BTAVGHUM.OUT?6423;TimeMethod=AtOrBefore"                                        
 [3] "°F"                                                                                            
 [4] "°F"                                                                                            
 [5] "°F"                                                                                            
 [6] "psia"                                                                                          
 [7] "°F"                                                                                            
 [8] "\\\\#\\asset1.2JT38601S.XQ01?6450;TimeMethod=AtOrBefore;pointtype=Float32;displaydigits=1"     
 [9] "\\\\#\\Degradation in Heat Rate (Comp Effic)?6275;TimeMethod=AtOrBefore"                       
[10] "\\\\#\\Degradation in Power Output (Comp Effic)?6274;TimeMethod=AtOrBefore"                    
[11] "\\\\#\\Dust?6273;TimeMethod=AtOrBefore"                                                        
[12] "°F"                                                                                            
[13] "\\\\#\\asset1.2FC54SUM.XQ01?6448;TimeMethod=AtOrBefore;pointtype=Float32;displaydigits=1"      
[14] "\\\\#\\asset1.BT0110.CTGgtFGvl01a?6801;TimeMethod=AtOrBefore;pointtype=Float32;displaydigits=1"
[15] "\\\\#\\asset1.2CTGFiredHours?6800;TimeMethod=AtOrBefore;pointtype=Float32;displaydigits=1"     
[16] "\\\\#\\asset1.2FT5050S.XQ01?6455;TimeMethod=AtOrBefore;pointtype=Float32;displaydigits=1"      
[17] "psi"                                                                                           
[18] "°F"                                                                                            
[19] "\\\\#\\asset1.2FT5150S.XQ01?6447;TimeMethod=AtOrBefore;pointtype=Float32;displaydigits=1"      
[20] "psi"                                                                                           
[21] "°F"                                                                                            
[22] "\\\\#\\asset1.2FT5250S.XQ01?6443;TimeMethod=AtOrBefore;pointtype=Float32;displaydigits=1"      
[23] "psi"                                                                                           
[24] "°F"                                                                                            
[25] "\\\\#\\asset1.2ZT35203.XQ01?6432;TimeMethod=AtOrBefore;pointtype=Float32;displaydigits=1"      
[26] "inHg"                                                                                          
[27] "\\\\#\\asset1.2FT36602X.ZQ01?6792;TimeMethod=AtOrBefore;pointtype=Float32;displaydigits=1"     
[28] "\\\\#\\asset1.2PT245.XQ01?6793;TimeMethod=AtOrBefore;pointtype=Float32;displaydigits=1"        
[29] "°F"
```

Comment: Try with regex lookaround `regmatches(mystr, regexpr("(?<=UOM\\=)\\w+", mystr, perl = TRUE))`

Comment: Thanks, it works for this example but fails for others - where I have some symbols - adding that to the question.

Comment: Please update with an example that fails as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following base R PCRE regex solution:

```r
[?;]UOM=\K[^;]+
```

Alternatively, a `stringr` solution like

```r
library(stringr)
str_match(x, "[?;]UOM=([^;]+)")[,2]
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WpSxRE/1). *Details*:

- `[?;]` - a `?` or `;` char
- `UOM=` - a `UOM=` substring
- `\K` - [match reset operator](https://www.regular-expressions.info/keep.html)
- `[^;]+` - one or more chars other than `;` char.

See the [R demo](https://ideone.com/KX70R8):

```r
x <- c("\\\\Server-01?6cf038ea-d583-4860-9488-67ee59c767c2\\expnum.2PDT35103?6438;TimeMethod=AtOrBefore;UOM=inHg;pointtype=Float32;displaydigits=1", 
"\\\\Server02-01?6cf038ea-d583-4860-9488-67ee59c767c2\\testnum.2BTAVGBARPR.OUT?6449;TimeMethod=AtOrBefore;UOM=inHg", 
"\\\\Server02-01?6cf038ea-d583-4860-9488-67ee59c767c2\\testnum3.2PT39248S.XQ01?6453;TimeMethod=AtOrBefore;UOM=psia;pointtype=Float32;displaydigits=1",
"\\\\Server02-01?6cf038ea-d583-4860-9488-67ee59c767c2\\testnum.2TE36112.XQ01?6454;TimeMethod=AtOrBefore;UOM=°F;pointtype=Float32;displaydigits=1")
regmatches(x, regexpr("[?;]UOM=\\K[^;]+", x, perl=TRUE))
## => [1] "inHg" "inHg" "psia" "°F"  
library(stringr)
str_match(x, "[?;]UOM=([^;]+)")[,2]
## => [1] "inHg" "inHg" "psia" "°F"
```

Comment: Hi, when I run this for a `data.table` column it only returns results for entries where a match is found and ignores the rest. Using it via `lapply` or `sapply` returns an error - I've updated my question to show a `data.table` - can you suggest a way to make it work there?

Comment: There now - accidentally pasted sth confidential so had to delete that first.

Comment: @Gautam Ok, so I get `[1] "inHg" NA     "°F"   "°F"   "°F"   "psia" "°F"   NA     NA     NA     NA     "°F"   NA     NA     NA     NA     "psi"  "°F"   NA     "psi"  "°F"   NA     "psi"  "°F"   NA     "inHg" NA     NA     "°F"` with the current solution. What do you expect? Keep the original text if there is no match?

Comment: @Gautam If you mean that, use `stringr::str_replace(dt$ConfigString, ".*[?;]UOM=([^;]+).*", "\\1")`

Comment: I'm getting a 15-element output without NAs - unlike what you're getting

Comment: `stringr` returns addl. text - unlike your other solution. the workaround is to use `dat[grepl('UOM', ConfigString), uom := stringr::str_replace(ConfigString, ".*[?;]UOM=([^;]+).*", "\\1")]`